# fmt:formatDate and timeZone

Tags: mysql, timezone, jstl

I have fields in a Mysql database typed *datetime*.

I store, for example, a payment's date with next Java code:

```
payment.setCreatedOn(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

In my view layer I use [fmt:formatDate](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) to format dates:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${payment.createdOn}" pattern="EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
```

My server is in London and my application's users are in Vienna. The time showing is delayed probably because of different time zones. I can use a *timeZone* Parameter in fmt:formatDate.

> timeZone: Time zone in which to
>   represent the formatted time.

After searching in Google, I think the value *Europe/Vienna* is valid for *timeZone* parameter.

Does anyone knows if there is list anywhere of the valid timeZone strings?

Answer (score 1):

Sergio - I'm sure you've long since found it anyway ...

Here's the [homepage for the Olson database](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm) or 'zoneinfo' which is the definitive source of TZ info.

And here's a [nice wiki](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/xtra/tzdatepick.html)  for browsing zones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list for the IBM JDK, a little dated but has full list:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/adrtzval.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the international time (UTC/Zulu) to add the following schedule client time use, for example "GMT+1". See this example.

Put this parameter as argument in your server to set UTC time use, in this case is for tomcat:

**-Duser.timezone="UTC"**

```
/* Java */      

@RequestMapping(value = "/web", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
public String web(Model model, HttpSession session, Locale locale) {

    Date today = new Date();
    model.addAttribute("currentTime", today);
    model.addAttribute("timezone", "GMT+1");

    return "web";
}
```

To show date choose your pattern you want (properties)

```
/* JSP web */

<fmt:timeZone value="${timezone}">
<spring:message code="date_format_dateMin" var="pattern"/>
<fmt:formatDate value="${currentTime}" timeZone="${timezone}" pattern="${pattern}" var="searchFormated" />
<span class="innerLabel">${searchFormated}</span>   
</fmt:timeZone>

/* Properties */

date_format_dateMin=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm
date_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss    
date_format2=yyyy/MM/dd
date_format3_js=yy/mm/dd
date_format4_time=HH:mm
date_format4=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```